# What word would an American child use instead of "disgruntled"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, emotions

If you have children, could you please show this image to them and ask them what word they'd use to describe the emotion the person in the image below?

[image: rage comic the "are you fucking kidding me" face]

Young children don't really use the word 'disgruntled,' do they? So, a **simpler** word for this emotion, (simple, meaning 'happy', 'sad,' etc.) would be helpful.

The emotion that I'm trying to capture is sort of an "are you fucking kidding me!" feeling.

I am making educational flash cards for learning English emotion words, and I need a word that means 'disgruntled', but it needs to be a word someone a younger person who's less than 14 years old would understand.

Comment: I'm 60ish and I don't think I would have come up with "disgruntled", either. I'm not even sure what I would say, it looks like a mix of sad and angry.

Comment: I'm not sure that a survey like this is an appropriate question for SE. From https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask: "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: My dictionary says that "disgruntled" means "angry or dissatisfied".

Comment: Seriously? No, I mean "seriously". That's what his internal monologue is saying right now.

Answer (score 2):

To a teenager, that guy looks *pissed*, or *pissed off.*

The more reputable dictionaries haven't fully caught up to the word's expanded meaning; [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pissed) has for its second usage

> slang, often vulgar: ANGRY, IRRITATED —often used with "off"

This is true, but younger speakers (and I am one of them)  now use it to capture a wider range of emotions, including annoyance, anger, disappointment, rankle, disdain, outrage and dissatisfaction. I don't have any extra citations for this usage, other than the fact that I myself use and witness it being used in this sort of context. I frequently hear *"He's pissed at that new guy*," "*that paper pissed him off,"* or "*You're pissing me off!*"

The only caveat is that it's not exactly a word you'd want to go around teaching. It's a crude way to put it.

Comment: "Mad" also came to mind (as in "the teacher is mad at me", not as in "they locked the mad man in the asylum"). But "pissed" is certainly good.

Answer (score 1):

A young child would describe the person as **grumpy,** [defined by The Free Dictionary as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/grumpy)

> surly or ill-tempered; discontentedly or sullenly irritable; grouchy.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture (furrowed brow) and from what I think you described (*Really? WTF. Uh, I don’t think so. Um, no.*), that person is ***skeptical***, which — according to *Merriam-Webster* — means “marked by *skepticism*”:

> **skepticism** *noun*
> **1 :** an attitude of doubt or a disposition to incredulity either in general or toward a particular object
>  <sub>Source:
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skepticism)</sub>

Comment: I don't think "skepticism" captures the irritation I read from the illustration.